# Pick element from xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this code to pick up foods and foodplaces from XML 
Att first i have stored the name of each restuarnt in a string list
and i want to pick the food that this restaurants in the lists reservs

```
 foreach(var restaurant in restaurants)
        {
            List<foodplace> foodPlaces = (from _foodplaces in xmlDocument.Element("foodplaces").Elements("foodplace")
                                          where _foodplaces.Value == restaurant 
                                          select new foodplace
                                          {
                                              day = (from day in _foodplaces.Elements(thisDay)
                                                     let list = day.Elements("food").Take(3).ToList()
                                                     select new DayOfWeek
                                                     {
                                                         food1 = (list.Count > 0 ? list[0].Value : string.Empty),
                                                         food2 = (list.Count > 1 ? list[1].Value : string.Empty),
                                                         food3 = (list.Count > 2 ? list[2].Value : string.Empty)
                                                     }).FirstOrDefault()
                                          }).ToList();
```

The problem is that _foodplaces returns value from xmldoxument that lookslike this

```
   \n\n\n\t the litle inddian \t\n\n\n
```

and the restuarant value is a string looks like this "the litle indian"

and so the linq statement returns null becuse _foodplace is not restuarant
how to come arround this

Answer (score 0):

To remove whitespace and perhaps consider case sensitivity:

```
where String.Equals(_foodplaces.Value.Trim(), restaurant, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string nameToSearch = "Restaurant12";
string xml = File.ReadAllText(<<pathtoxml>>, Encoding.Default);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
//this depends on your xml structure: i assumed that the attribute of the restaurant is name
XmlNode node = doc.selectSingleNode("foodplaces/foodplace[@name = '"+nameToSearch +"']");
if(node != null){
    foreach(XmlNode foodNode in node.selectNodes("food")){
        //Do something with the foodnode
        //e.g. foodNode.SelectsingleNode("Price").InnerText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `PreserveWhitespace` property of `XMLDocument` to `false` before loading xml.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
doc.Load("your.xml");
```